# Is there a way to package your Love2D game into a bytecode distributable?

Tags: lua, love2d, luajit

i plan on comercially releasing games soon, so i would like to find out a way to compile to bytecode and then fuse it into an executable. I have been searching for a way for literal months, but i haven't found a way, let me tell you what happens when i do try to do a method.

So doing jit.version, i can see Love2D uses 2.1.0beta3, which is the version i use to do `luajit -b test.lua test.bc`. After i do do that i proceed to remove the contents of the .lua file, and add different code to it.

Let's show you what i originally had inside of test.lua (the code i compiled):

```lua
local test = {}

function test:load()
    print("Worked.")
end

return test
```

So this is the code i compile, i then remove the contents of it and add this instead:

```lua
local f = assert(love.filesystem.load("test.bc"))

return f()
```

and then in my main.lua file i do this:

```lua
function love.load()
    local testclass = require("test")
    testclass:load()
end
```

When i do that, i produce this error (Before you ask, there's no syntax error in the Lua code before compilation.):

```
Error

test.lua:1: Syntax error: test.bc: cannot load incompatible bytecode



Traceback

[love "callbacks.lua"]:228: in function 'handler'
[C]: in function 'load'
test.lua:1: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
main.lua:3: in function 'load'
[love "callbacks.lua"]:136: in function <[love "callbacks.lua"]:135>
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

I genuinly have been looking for a way for literal months, if someone could help out, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The incompatible bytecode error might be from the LuaJIT version you used not being built to use GC64 mode while Love2D could of been built with it enabled. If you build LuaJIT from source from using the HEAD of v2.1 branch its enabled by default.

Comment: Precompiling is neither recommended with JIT nor compatible across different operating systems. It also doesn't make your project more secure or prevents piracy. Why do you want to compile?

Comment: @Luke100000 JIT bytecode is portable: "The generated bytecode is portable and can be loaded on any architecture that LuaJIT supports, independent of word size or endianess. However, the bytecode compatibility versions must match. Bytecode stays compatible for dot releases (x.y.0 → x.y.1), but may change with major or minor releases (2.0 → 2.1) or between any beta release. Foreign bytecode (e.g. from Lua 5.1) is incompatible and cannot be loaded." - http://luajit.org/extensions.html

Comment: @Luke100000 also, re "[it] also doesn't make your project more secure or prevents piracy": It does make your project more secure by obscuring the sources ("security by obscurity"), making it harder to reverse. Of course you shouldn't rely on this as your sole means of security as it's easy to break. It doesn't prevent piracy either, but it does make *modifying* your game much harder, esp. if you strip debug symbols; this may help against cheating and against pirated, modded copies "selling" better than the original. Disclaimer: I've never distributed compiled Lua, I only made free software.

Comment: Obfuscation might be more helpful than bytecode for these purposes however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So doing `jit.version`, i can see Love2D uses 2.1.0beta3, which is the version i use to do `luajit [...]`

Unfortunately, the assumption that LuaJIT version numbers would be sane is wrong. LuaJIT has been on 2.1.0-beta3 for years, despite numerous changes; Mike Pall's motivation for stopping to explicitly release new versions is unclear, but it seems that you are supposed to just use latest master.

Thus, to make sure that you're compiling your bytecode with the same LuaJIT version LÖVE uses, compile it from within LÖVE using `string.dump`.

Note that - contrary to PUC Lua - `string.dump` [generates portable bytecode on LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/extensions.html):

> The generated bytecode is portable and can be loaded on any architecture that LuaJIT supports, independent of word size or endianess. However, the bytecode compatibility versions must match. Bytecode stays compatible for dot releases (x.y.0 → x.y.1), but may change with major or minor releases (2.0 → 2.1) or between any beta release. Foreign bytecode (e.g. from Lua 5.1) is incompatible and cannot be loaded.

You can also set a `strip` flag, which will be helpful to remove debug information to make reversing harder:

> An extra argument has been added to string.dump(). If set to true, 'stripped' bytecode without debug information is generated. This speeds up later bytecode loading and reduces memory usage. See also the -b command line option.

So, let's first use the following `main.lua`, which assumes your project folder as the current working directory:

```
-- Compile `test.lua` to bytecode, strip debug info
local bytecode = string.dump(assert(love.filesystem.load("test.lua")), true)

local f = assert(io.open("test.bc", "wb"))
f:write(bytecode)
f:close()

print("Compiled `test.lua` to `test.bc`")
love.event.quit()
```

Now execute `love .` inside your project directory to compile `test.lua` to `test.bc`. After doing this, you can replace `test.lua` with:

```lua
return assert(love.filesystem.load("test.bc"))()
```

and replace `main.lua` with

```lua
function love.load()
    local testclass = require("test")
    testclass:load()
end
```

Running this using `love .` prints `Worked.` as expected.

---

Automatizing this build process using Lua scripts, shell scripts or Makefiles is left as an exercise to the reader.

You could also try figuring out the exact LuaJIT commit LÖVE uses to compile that LuaJIT version yourself, which would allow you to use `luajit -b test.lua test.bc`.

Comment: Thank you for responding.
I have done the exact steps, putting the original code in test.lua, compiling it by doing string.dump (the code you provided) in main.lua, then replacing everything in test.lua by the return statement, then changing main.lua to require test.lua as `testclass`. When i do this, i get the following error:

```
Error
test.lua:1: Syntax error: test.bc: cannot load malformed bytecode


Traceback

etc..
```

I tried compiling it twice, and i get the same error.

Comment: @MielLand are you on Windows? I noticed I made a small mistake: I opened the file using `w`. On Unix (where I tested) this doesn't matter, there is no difference between `w` and `wb`. But Windows performs line feed normalization to CRLF. I've edited my answer to use `wb` for opening the file. Could you try again?

Comment: Oh my god. You may be the smartest human being i have ever met. You DO NOT understand how happy this makes me, i have literally, literally been searching for MONTHS and everyone always raises "why would you want to do that?" "no reason to." instead of helping. You are honestly the best, if i could EVER do anything to repay you, i would, thank you, thank you so so much for helping.

Comment: @MielLand Thanks, you're welcome :) consider using an obfuscator if you want to make reversing and modifying your game harder; LuaJIT bytecode can be decompiled (although local variable names and much of the code structure will be lost in the process).

Comment: @MielLand - A NeoVIM (Texteditor with syntaxhighlight) for Windows exists and uses LuaJIT / FFI (with modified Lua 5.1) as LÖVE do - I suggest it and i use it not only for Lua as a "Standard App" for file extensions - It contains a help system and a good start could be in command mode: ```:help lua``` or ```:help luado``` or ```:help luafile```